# how to activate or modify keyboard shortcuts on eclipse software?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse

I am running Eclipse for PHP Developers Version: Helios Service Release 2 on windows 8.

I use commonly things like Ctrl + ⇧ + C to comment or Ctrl + left click to go to a variable or method declaration .

these keyboard shortcuts does not work nomore.
How can i reactivate them?

Answer (score 1):

Window > Preferences > General > Keys

For default bindings take a look at :

- [Juno](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-keybindings.htm)
- [Helios](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench.htm)

Comment: thanks , i have restored defaults and it is still not working, any ideas?

Comment: @Matoeil You're welcome. Why don't you use `F3` and `Ctrl + /` ? BTW, restoring the default shortcuts won't fix this for you, cause they are not default settings. Easily find them and change them as you wish.

Comment: what is this supposed to do? ctrl+shift+c is listed as default for toggle comment !?

Comment: :) sorry, I mixed it up with Ctrl + up + c

Comment: @Matoeil `Ctrl + /` comment/uncomment and `F3` to go the method definition

Comment: thanks but this is juno and not helios documentation . it does not work for me. i believe something interfere with the normal behaviour coz my ctrl+shift+c was working before